How to solve the problem of " undefined symbol: MKL_Get_Version"?
/miniconda3/envs/kino_nerf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kilonerf_cuda.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: MKL_Get_Version

I have tried to install mkl and mkl-service using Conda, but the question is still not solved.

$ conda install mkl mkl-service
Channels:

- defaults
- anaconda
  Platform: linux-64
  Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
  Solving environment: done


My env.
$ nvcc -V

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Sep_15_19:10:02_PDT_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.1, V11.1.74
Build cuda_11.1.TC455_06.29069683_0

$ conda list torch

- Name                    Version                   Build  Channel

  torch                     1.8.1+cu111              pypi_0    pypi

  torchaudio                0.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi

  torchvision               0.9.1+cu111              pypi_0    pypi



Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run_nerf.py", line 21, in \<module\>
    from run_nerf_helpers import *
File "/code_space/kilonerf/run_nerf_helpers.py", line 6, in \<module\>
import kilonerf_cuda
/miniconda3/envs/kino_nerf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kilonerf_cuda.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: MKL_Get_Version

